# How can i fix my beginner if and else code?

Tags: c#, .net

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace MyFirstTest
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Int32 value = 57;

            if (value < 10)

                Console.WriteLine("Value is less than 10");

            else (value = 57)

                Console.WriteLine("Value is 57!");

            else

                Console.WriteLine("Value is greater than 10");


            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

I am a complete beginner and have just started learning C#. I have tried to create a snippet of code using the if and else statements.

When it gets to the below, it throws me some squiggly lines and expects `{ }`.

```
else (value = 57) 
Console.WriteLine("Value is 57!");`
```

How can i go about fixing this? An explanation would also be great to help a beginner! Thank you in advance.

Comment: Change it to `else if (value == 57)`

Comment: Just use the `else if` block: `else if (value == 57)  { Console.WriteLine("Value is 57!"); }`.

Comment: `else (value == 57) ` as `=` is for assignment and not for equality check

Comment: Cheers guys. Patrick, could you elaborate on what == does?

Comment: `==` is the equality checking operator, and `=` is the assignment operator.

Comment: Ah okay, thank you everyone!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly you are using if...else if...else Statement, rather than using else for the second time, you have to use else if as you are checking like if the first condition is true, if not true then else if, second condition is true then at last we use else, if any of the above mentioned conditions are not true.
Secondly, to compare, we use == not =

So here your code goes like

```
if(value < 10)
{ 
    Console.WriteLine("Value is less than 10");
}
else if(value == 57)
{ 
    Console.WriteLine("Value is 57!");
}
else
{ 
    Console.WriteLine("Value is greater than 10");
}
```

For more information see control statements at https://www.tutorialspoint.com/csharp/if_else_statement_in_csharp.htm

Answer (score 3):

```
namespace MyFirstTest
{
   class Program
   {
       static void Main(string[] args)
       {
           Int32 value = 57;

           if (value < 10)
           {
               Console.WriteLine("Value is less than 10");
           }
           else if(value == 57)
           {
               Console.WriteLine("Value is 57!");
           }
           else
           {
               Console.WriteLine("Value is greater than 10");
           }

           Console.ReadLine();
       }
   }
}
```